# slideUp different on actual page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

I am trying to use the `slideUp()` JQuery function on a bunch of items without images. The code I've written works fine in JSFiddle, but on my actual page, it collapses in a clunky way.

Why are they not acting the same way?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKKrM/)

To activate the function on the page, press the checkbox in the right menu

[Real page](http://xn--nstvedhandel-6cb.dk/naestved/public/)

Comment: if it works fine on fiddle, then there is something else in your code that interferes with this, check the css and js ,, and make sure you have correct html syntax (closing tags are there .. )

Comment: how is it action exactly on your page ? a demonstration would be good

Comment: that is dangerous, try not giving links to your computer unless you have enough security :)

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan it is not local, you can hack ..

Comment: @CME64: Calm Down :P it's just an IP, every website has one.

Comment: not accessible your link..

Comment: I know but they implement security before distributing it :P

Comment: I've put it on a domain instead :-)

Comment: Don't put the js at the end of the page, always put it in the head, I know it won't work this way because you are not loading it after the doms are done loading,, use `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });`

Comment: @Maeh: it's too bad the international characters didn't show. `http://næstvedhandel.dk/naestved/public/` works fine though :) http://næstvedhandel.dk/naestved/public/

Comment: please put your code in a fiddle, or a bin,, I can't experiment with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sifting through CSS for a few minutes and I found a solution, I have made a list of corrections.

[Here is the CSS code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uyrGcbbn), it does all the fixes I have mentioned below.

### Manual Fix

Find `#middlewrapper #content .contentbox`, disable `float:left`.

```
#middlewrapper #content .contentbox {
    width: 650px;
    padding: 15px;
    /* float: left; */
    background-color: white;
}
```

Find `#middlewrapper #content .contentbox_shadow`, disable `float:left`.

```
#middlewrapper #content .contentbox_shadow {
    width: 690px;
    height: 20px;
    /* float: left; */
    background-image: url('http://xn--nstvedhandel-6cb.dk/naestved/public/css/../images/content_skygge.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Find `#middlewrapper #content`, disable `float:left`.

```
#middlewrapper #content {
    width: 690px;
    /* float: left; */
}
```

Finally, find `#middlewrapper #content .contentbox`, after it's definition, place `#content`.

```
#content {
    width: 680px;
    float: left;
}
```

Do not delete or alter the definition of `#middlewrapper #content` found a few lines later.